# Variable initialization & scope in Golang

Tags: go

I am learning go lang and I came across below code

```
var kvstore = make(map[string][]byte)

// this function instantiates the database
func init_db() {
    kvstore = make(map[string][]byte)
}

// put inserts a new key value pair or updates the value for a
// given key in the store
func put(key string, value []byte) {
    kvstore[key] = value
}

// get fetches the value associated with the key
func get(key string) []byte {
    v, _ := kvstore[key]
    return v
}
```

I have 2 doubts:

1. why is it required to initialize `kvstore` variable once globally and then once in `init_db` function?
2. When someone calls `put/get` function from other module how is the state of kvstore maintained? (In 'C' we generally have to explicitly pass the data structure to the function but in this case put or get directly works on global kvstore variable)

Comment: You can reinitialize with `init_db()`

Comment: It won't be possible to call get/put from other modules because these symbols are not exported. The first letter must be uppercase for the symbol/identifier to be exported. Kvstore is defined as a global variable but since it's first letter is not uppercase, it's not directly visible and accessible from external modules. It's like a static variable in C.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to initialize kvstore twice.

You can think of the global kvstore variable as something similar to variable with static duration in C. And it's not safe to access map concurrently with writes. You might need to synchronize, just like accessing static global variable in C.

Comment: That's not entirely accurate. The current implementation allows one to safely use put/get without calling init_db. init_db can be used to clear the db. Whether that's desirable is a different story but the double initialization is not equivalent to the single init.

Comment: @pvg Good point. I think `init_db` should be renamed to `clear_db`, because whenever you call the function it always just **clear the db**. And `init_db` sounds like a function that must called before using some library/module.

Comment: It seems to be some skeleton/starter code from a CMU distributed systems class. So there's probably no changing it or thinking too many deep thoughts about its design! https://github.com/CMU-440-F16/p0

Comment: @pvg yes, this is the code from CMU distributed class assignment.

Comment: @cshu: Regarding the variable `kvstore`. If we declare some variable globally in some module then does it mean it will be globally accessible to all other modules? (contrary to 'C' where you need `extern` keyword for that)

Comment: @Nullpointer `Kvstore` is globally accessible. `kvstore` is not. The capital letter determines accessibility. Actually package is closer to namespace in C++. Storage Duration, Namespace, and Linkage. These 3 are 3 different things.